# Useless store causing crash

Tags: jvm, jasmin

I have this jasmin assembly, which is the equivalent of the simplification of JVM assembly produced by a bytecode rewriter I am writing.  It crashes when run, but works if I remove the `sipush` and the first store.

```
.method public simple()V
    .limit stack 4
    sipush        12345
    istore_1
    getstatic java/lang/System/out Ljava/io/PrintStream;
    sipush        12345
    ldc 12345
    iadd
    invokevirtual java/io/PrintStream/println(I)V
    return
.end method
```

Does the JVM require every store to be used by a load?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`istore_1` stores a value to the local variable #1, but your methods has no locals.

The method will become valid if you add the following line:

```
    .limit locals 2
```